# ¿Por qué no imprime en pantalla el caracter "+"?

Tags: c

Pues tengo este problema: 
Tengo un puntero con un valor y quiero pasarlo a un array para trabajar con él.

He hecho esto:

```
char arr[1024];
char *operation = "1+2+3+4";
strcpy(arr, operation);
char almacen[1024];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
{
    sprintf(&almacen[i], "%.1s",&arr[i]);
    i++;
}
```

El problema es que luego al hacer print:

```
for (int e = 0; e < 7; e++) {
    printf("%s\n",almacen[e]);
}
```

lo que obtengo como salida es:

1

2

3

4

Donde en lugar de "+" se ha impreso un carácter en blanco, y quisiera saber por qué y como podría solucionarlo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Porque está guardado con strcpy desde un puntero, de manera que solo arr[0] contiene el completo del puntero. Arr[1] contiene todo a excepción del primer caracter, arr[2] todo a excepción del los dos primeros y así sucesivamente. De manera que con "%.1s" consigo quedarme solo con el primer carácter de cada salida de arr[i], alacenándolo en almacen[i] y así obtengo separar "1+2+3+4" en {"1", "+", "2","+","3","+","4"} (o esa es la intención)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, esta línea de código:

```c
printf("%s\n", almacen[e]);
```

Hará que la función `printf` genere un fallo de segmentación (acceder a memoria que no le pertenece al programa) y esto se debe porque no estás usando el especificador de formato adecuado. El `%s` imprime una *secuencia de caracteres*, no un *caracter*. Por lo tanto, se debe usar `%c`.

**Corrección:**

```c
printf("%c\n", almacen[e]);
```

O también podrías eliminar el bucle for e imprimir directamente así:

```c
printf("%s\n", almacen);
```

> > No imprime caracter “+” (C)

Analicemos este código:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
{
    sprintf(&almacen[i], "%.1s", &arr[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Esta línea:

```c
sprintf(&almacen[i], "%.1s", &arr[i]);
```

Simplemente guardará el caracter (solo almacena uno porque has usado el especificador `%.1s`) en una determinada posición del *array* `almacen`, sin embargo, la función `sprintf` agregará al final un caracter nulo.

**Ejemplo:**

Cuando `i = 0`. Estaríamos guardando el caracter `1` en la posición `0` del *array* `almacen`, pero la función `sprintf` asignará el caracter nulo en la posición `1` del *array* `almacen`.

Entonces, el *array* `almacen` en memoria va quedando así:

```c
Memory Address: 0x0  0x1  0x2 ...
Dato:            1   \0
```

Luego incrementamos dos veces `i` y ahora vale `2`.
Volvemos aplicar la misma lógica.

En la posición `2` guardamos el caracter `2` y luego `sprintf` almacena el caracter nulo en la posición `3` y así sucesivamente. Entonces el *array* `almacen` va quedando así:

```c
Memory Address: 0x0  0x1  0x2  0x3
Dato:           1    \0    2   \0
```

**¿Por qué la función sprintf siempre agrega un caracter nulo?**

La función [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) guarda el contenido de la cadena formateada en una nueva cadena, sin embargo, esa **nueva cadena** debe tener al final un caracter nulo, de lo contrario, no pudiéramos recorrer la *cadena* a través de un bucle, porque no encontraríamos un **fin**.

> > Donde en lugar de "+" se ha impreso un carácter en blanco, y quisiera saber por qué

Lo que se imprime en pantalla no es un caracter en blanco, simplemente es el **caracter nulo** y lo comprobamos de esta forma:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
{
    sprintf(&almacen[i], "%.1s", &arr[i]);
    i++;
}
printf("%s\n", almacen);
```

**Salida en pantalla:**

```c
1
```

Solo nos imprimió un dato. ¿Sabes porque pasó esto? Porque la función `printf` encontró el **caracter nulo** y eso indica el **fin de la cadena**.

> > ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Si eliminamos la sentencia `i++` que está al final del bucle, el programa imprimirá el resultado esperado:

```c
int main ()
{
    char arr[1024];
    char *operation = "1+2+3+4";
    strcpy(arr, operation);
    char almacen[1024];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
        sprintf(&almacen[i], "%.1s", &arr[i]);

    printf("%s\n", almacen);
    for (int e = 0; e < 7; e++) 
        printf("%c\n", almacen[e]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Salida en pantalla:**

```c
1+2+3+4
1
+
2
+
3
+
4
```

**¿Por qué funcionó?**

Volvamos analizar este código:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
    sprintf(&almacen[i], "%.1s", &arr[i]);
```

Cuando `i = 0`. Se guardará en la posición `0` el caracter `1` y en la posición `1` el caracter nulo.

Entonces, el *array* `almacen` en memoria quedaría así:

```c
0x0  0x1 ..
 1    \0
```

Cuando `i = 1`, volvemos hacer lo mismo, insertamos en la posición `1` el caracter `+` y sobrescribimos el caracter nulo que estaba en la posición `1`, al final la función `sprintf` inserta el caracter nulo en la posición `2` y así sucesivamente.

Quedando en memoria de esta forma:

```c
Memory Address: 0x0  0x1  0x2  ...
Dato:           1     +   \0
```